# How to prevent Firebase from remembering Google Account on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-account

I am programming and Android application and I am using Firebase to allow the user to sign in with his/her Google account. The problem is that immediately when the user starts the app and presses the "log in" button, he/she is logged into his/her account. Only after uninstalling and reinstalling the app will the user have the option to log in to a different account (and then that account will be remembered). How can I prevent Firebase from automatically logging the user in?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707133/google-firebase-sign-out-and-forget-user-in-android-app