# How to force google account chooser after sign out in android firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase Google Auth, signing out and logging in again will log in with last signed account. How can I make account chooser every time?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38707133/4815718

Answer (score 3):

This part of Firebase Authentication with just a Google Sign In Button in place has given me a lot of nightmares, and if you have encountered the same issue, then I can assure that this answer will save you tons of hours!

Wherever you are implementing the Sign Out functionality, remember to use this line of code and you are good to go.

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn


GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build())
.signOut()
```

This is a kotlin code.

Comment: This is not working for me. Even after signout, i'm not getting account chooser screen. I'm using this dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth [Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L160-L172) sample code provides the following few steps for sign out

Declare Globally these two variables

```
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
```

Add these lines in onCreate method

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Now for signOut

```
private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        mAuth.signOut();

        // Google sign out
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }
```

It's easy, and it will work. Cheers!

Comment: This is not working for me. Even after signout, i'm not getting account chooser screen. I'm using this dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'.