# Perform sign out from Firebase Google account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I did everything as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38707133/4057688) question & configured sign out event like this:

```
public static void SignOut() {
    // Google sign out
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess())
                        Log.wtf("success", "signed out");
                    if (status.isInterrupted())
                        Log.wtf("interrupted", "not signed out");
                    if (status.isCanceled())
                        Log.wtf("cancelled", "sign out cancelled");
                }
            });
}
```

However, following error is thrown when `SignOut()` is called:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaas.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaav.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaat.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzc.signOut(Unknown Source)

Before `SignOut()`, `mAuth.signOut()` is invoked.

How can I tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code m facing same problem after this signout from google account done successfully..

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logout Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: so, the first line in `onResult()` solved the problem for you?