# Firebase Android - how to login as different user (after signing in with Google)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, firebaseui

**Edit - a key thing that I didn't realise at when writing is that this happens when you use Google as an authentication provider**

I've set up my Android app so that I can log in and out using Firebase Authentication.

But when I log in, I'm not presented with any options that would let me log in as a different use - it just auto-logs me into the same account I logged into last time.

How can I switch the user account I use to log in?

Code from my main Activity:

```
    // Authentication stuff
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private val btnSignIn: Button by lazy { findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn) }
    val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()) { res ->
        if (res.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            refreshSigninInfo()
        } else {
            showToast("Sign in failed - do you have internet connection?")
        }
    }
    private fun refreshSigninInfo() {  // Called in onCreate() 
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        auth.currentUser?.let {
            btnSignIn.text = "Signed in as ${it.email}\nTap to sign out"
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
                auth.signOut()
                refreshSigninInfo()
            }
        } ?: run {
            btnSignIn.text = "Tap to sign in"
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
                val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(arrayListOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(), AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                    .build()
                signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
                // HERE, upon launch, this this should give the user 
                // the option of selecting a different sign-in account
                // but instead, if the user has previously signed in, 
                // it just directly signs the user in without the option 
                // to change account
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Thank Alex, I added a comment to the code explaining where the issue is.  There's no error - it's just I'm trying to get it to let me choose a different user when I signed in on a device that had a previous sign in.   Currently it just directly signs me in without allowing the switch.

Comment: Are you sure signed out from Google first?

Comment: I'm sure I've signed out because I've called `auth.signOut()` and `auth.currentUser` is now `null`.

Comment: So it turns out you're right Alex, I hadn't signed out of Google.  For reasons I don't understand the normal approach of signing out of google client wasn't working either - the solution I posted below ended up working.

Comment: If you want to switch to a custom implementation and stop using a library, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327075/851699).

Key thing was to sign out with:

```
AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener {
    refreshSigninInfo()
}
```

Instead of `auth.signOut()`.  This way you get signed out of both Google and the firebase auth, so you aren't automatically logged in next time through Google.

Full Code (in my main activity - includes some references to buttons and stuff that you won't have):

```
    // Authentication stuff
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private val textLoginInfo: TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.textLoginInfo) }
    private val btnSignIn: ImageButton by lazy { findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn) }
    val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()) { res ->
        if (res.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            refreshSigninInfo()
        } else {
            showToast("Sign in failed - do you have internet connection?")
        }
    }
    private fun refreshSigninInfo() {  // Called in onCreate()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        auth.currentUser?.let {
            btnSignIn.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_white_24dp)
            textLoginInfo.text = "Signed in: ${it.email}"
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener {
                    refreshSigninInfo()
                }
            }
        } ?: run {
            btnSignIn.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_white_24dp)
            textLoginInfo.text = "Not Signed in"
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
                val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                    .setAvailableProviders(arrayListOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(), AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                    .build()
                signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
            }
        }
    }
```