# Not able to get the array values from firebase database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check whether the **signed in** user is an authorized user from the JSON array in Firebase Database. How do I get the value of email field from Firebase. ?

This is the **model** `User` class:

```
public class User {

    ArrayList<User> email;

    public User() {}

    public ArrayList<User> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(ArrayList<User> email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

For getting the `email` from `userslist`, I used this logic.

```
usersListDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User userEmail = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        ArrayList<String> userEmailFromDatabase = userEmail.getEmail();
                        Log.d(TAG, "User email from Database: "+userEmailFromDatabase);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Logged in User email: " + user.getEmail());
                    }
```

But when I try to get the emails from the the database I get the following exception and my app crashes.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.apvolution.amapp.model.User
```

How do I get an 'email`from the`userslist`field ? How do I loop through the entire`usersList` ?

This is the database structure in my Firebase console.

```
amapp-731b2addclose
   + messages
   + version
   - userslist
      - email
         |
         | -- 0: "abc@gmail.com"
         | -- 1: "xyz@gmail.com"
         | -- 2: "ghi@gmail.com"
         | -- 3: "mno@gmail.com"
```

LogCat details:

```
05 - 13 21: 59: 37.418 16387 - 16387 / com.apvolution.bcm E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.apvolution.bcm, PID: 16387
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can 't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.apvolution.amapp.model.User
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.apvolution.bcm.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java: 260)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 757)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem is that you are trying to store your data in an `ArrayList` in stead of a `Map`. Change the type in `Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();` and your problem will be solved.

To get you data out from the `dataSnapshot` object, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userslist").child("email");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String firstEmail = (String) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue();
        String secondEmail = (String) dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue();
        String thirdEmail = (String) dataSnapshot.child("3").getValue();
        String fourthEmail = (String) dataSnapshot.child("4").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would change my model class `User` to this now. Do I use `GenericTypeIndicator` to pull up the data from firebase storage ?

Comment: Perfect. Keep me posted.

Comment: `Map<String, Object> email = new HashMap<>();

    User(){

    }

    public Map<String, Object> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }` This is what I used for model `User` now. Is that right ?

Comment: Great! Now how do I pull up the data, get the value from datasnapshot. Will `GenericTypeIndicator` work ?

Comment: You can use it but is no need. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144188/discussion-between-pc-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

Seems `DataSnapshot`'s `getValue(GenericTypeIndicator)` requires you to submit a `List<YourCustomModel>` rather than just `YourCustomModel`, see [this link from Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator). This means you should be doing:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>>() {};
List<User> userEmail = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

And then, from there, retrieve each email individually. You might want to recheck how you do your User model though, since it might not need it's own `ArrayList<>`

Comment: Appreciate it! Now I get this `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.apvolution.amapp.model.User`

Comment: anyway to update your post with a stack trace or something?

Comment: I think you should change the ArrayList<User> in your User model code to ArrayList<String>. That might solve it

Comment: could  you check what type exactly comes out of your dataSnapshot.getValue()? without putting any params.