# Firebase logout is not working

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have begin to use Firebase but my experience is terrible.

I cannot sign out user.

I have tried different things and spend all my 4 days to figure out how to sign out user but there is not clear option.

I want to sing out user totally so they can select another gmail account .

I have tried below code:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.unlink(user.getProviderId()); FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

inside of

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();//mAuth.signOut();
        //auth fail olarsa mAuth.signOut(); sil sonra yerne qoy
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
```

I have tried also this:[Properly log out a user from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541675/properly-log-out-a-user-from-android-app)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: When I click login it is not showing email list , it login with before email which I have selected before @AlexMamo

Comment: here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L160-L172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a newer version than me, I doubt they introduced a new bug. You mentioned `NullPointerException` earlier, so I suggest you make sure the GoogleApiClient you pass to `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent` is not null.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it also , and got not connected error then I have tried to put it to button click listener so it will have time to connect , and it worked!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Firebase Auth Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java) sample code, the sign-out for Google provider includes these steps.

Are you calling `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut()` when you sign-out? So, please use this code:

```
private void signOut() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google sign out
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                //do what you want
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: The current documentation for Google Sign-In states `To sign out a user, call signOut:

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getContext()
it gave error and I have tried it before

Comment: @user3175580 it is not enough because user cannot sign in with another account

Comment: @AlexAlex but using just this method I am able to view the email list again after clicking the Google button in my login activity. What version is your firebase auth dependency?

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4' 
i

Comment: @user3175580 11.0.4

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem, right now, the LogoutBtn is inside a drawer, like this:

```
case R.id.initiates_logout:
            if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Text1")
                        .setMessage("Text2")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();


                            }})
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
            }
            break;
```

And i cant select another account after the logout.

Comment: Though you did start this as your own question - it should be a comment not an answer here