# Firebase Google Logout is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` but I can't select another account after the logout. Right now the login and logout are in different activities, the `LoginActivity` have the normal Google login from the Firebase documentation, and the logout activity is a `Drawer` with the `LogoutBtn` like this:

```
case R.id.initiates_logout:
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Text1")
                    .setMessage("Text2")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            user.unlink(user.getProviderId());
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();


                        }})
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
        }
        break;
```

I also try this solution [Firebase logout is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552400/firebase-logout-is-not-working) but nothing work.

Comment: is this on device or emulator? kotlin or java? what version of android studio?

Comment: java, android device API 23 with android studio 2.3.3

Comment: ah, nevermind then. I have this issue with emulator, but running only Android Studio 3.0 canary 9