# Progress bar not showing during Sign Out

Tags: android, firebase

Please check the logout method.
When I try to log out progress bar is not showing.But the app does not crash and it works fine .

It moves to the next Activity perfectly.
I also tried to check the progress bar by giving a `Thread.sleep(2000)`  But still it is not working.

This the HomePage class code that I am attaching

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference mData;
TextView t;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public void logout(View v) throws InterruptedException {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void profile(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this,ProfilePage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(HomePage.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(progressBar,params);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  //  final String[] name = new String[1];
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginName);
    final String uid = mAuth.getUid();
    mData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            showData(dataSnapshot,uid);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Check your Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });



}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String uid) {
    User u = new User();
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

u.setName(ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class).getName());
}
    t.setText(u.getName());
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}


}
```

The Xml code for homepage activity

```
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ashwanths.helpwithfood.HomePage">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
    android:paddingEnd="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:paddingRight="20sp"
    android:paddingStart="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="20sp"
    android:text="Welcome "
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginName"
    android:layout_width="255dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:onClick="profile"
    android:text="Profile Page" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add a person" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:onClick="logout"
    android:text="SignOut" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Give Food" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Even in `OnDataChange()` the progress bar is not showing Please help me.

Comment: Tried implemented the call back method on "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();" afer that gone the progressbar

Comment: please provide your xml file here.

Comment: I hope this link help to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552400/firebase-logout-is-not-working

Comment: I attached the xml file

Comment: @ChintakPatel Why you need to xml file. They l've created the custom progressBar

Comment: @ManikandanK Yes, I need custom pogressbar xml file

Comment: @ManikandanK I don't want how to sign out I want to get the progress bar

Comment: @ChintakPatel, I hope, they i've not create the custome progress bar in xml file.

Comment: @ashwanths, Why you added the progressBar in layout. You direclty using "SHOW" and "HIDE" methods, It's working well

Comment: @ashwanths, How much time it takes to signout from `Firebase` in your app ?

Comment: @ChintakPatel, Good question. I thing so depanded on internet speed and network traffic.

One of the best way to acheive issues and using callback method()

Comment: @ChintakPatel it takes about 1 to 2 seconds .But I also used Thread.sleep(2000) to check whether its working but its not rather it sleeps for 2 seconds more and log's out